# PHP: Validating URL with Curl

Tags: php, curl

```
    $fileSource = "http://google.com";
    $ch = curl_init($fileSource);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($retcode != 200) {
        $error .= "The source specified is not a valid URL.";
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Here's my issue. When I use the above and set `$fileSource = "http://google.com";` it does not work, whereas if I set it to `$fileSource = "http://www.google.com/";` it works.

What's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One permanently redirects (301) to the `www.` domain, while the other one just replies OK (200).

Why are you only considering only the 200 status code as valid? Let CURL handle that for you:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> TRUE to fail silently if the HTTP code returned is greater than or
>   equal to 400. The default behavior is to return the page normally,
>   ignoring the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly telling curl to follow redirects

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

If that doesn't work you may need to spoof a user agent on some sites.

Also, if they are using JS redirects your out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is actually a result of a 301 redirect. Here's what I got back using a verbose curl from the command line

```
curl -vvvvvv http://google.com
* About to connect() to google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 173.194.43.34...
* connected
* Connected to google.com (173.194.43.34) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.25.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0) libcurl/7.25.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1b zlib/1.2.6 libidn/1.22
> Host: google.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://www.google.com/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Fri, 04 May 2012 04:03:59 GMT
< Expires: Sun, 03 Jun 2012 04:03:59 GMT
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
< Server: gws
< Content-Length: 219
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< 
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host google.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

However, if you do a curl on the actual www.google.com suggested in the 301 redirect, you'll get the following.

```
curl -vvvvvv http://www.google.com
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.228.19...
* connected
* Connected to www.google.com (74.125.228.19) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.25.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0) libcurl/7.25.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1b zlib/1.2.6 libidn/1.22
> Host: www.google.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 04 May 2012 04:05:25 GMT
< Expires: -1
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

I've truncated the remainder of google's response just to show the primary difference in the 200 OK vs 301 REDIRECT